# Rails Clearance, Unit Test Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, clearance

I'm having trouble getting the Clearance authentication to work with Rails controller unit testing. I've followed the instructions at https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance "Controller Test Helpers". How do you unit test controllers that require authentication?

I get the following error:

```
GoalsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in_as' for #<GoalsControllerTest:0x007f8c41c6b9c8>
    test/controllers/goals_controller_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:GoalsControllerTest>'
```

**test/test_helper.rb**

```
require 'clearance/test_unit'
```

**test/controller/goals_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class GoalsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    user = User.new(fname: "Test", lname: "User", email: "testuser@test.com", password: "password")
    sign_in_as(user)
    @goal = goals(:one)
  end
```

Comment: Is the 'sign_in_as' method defined inside ApplicationController or in a helper module?

Answer (score 2):

i've same problem with you, but now fixed by this answer https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/695

Enable the Middleware in Test:

```
# config/environments/test.rb
MyRailsApp::Application.configure do
  # ...
  config.middleware.use Clearance::BackDoor
  # ...
end
```

In my `test/test_helper.rb` file, I wrote this following code.

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def manual_sign_in_as(user)
    post session_url, params: {
      session: {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Rails 5 subclasses controller tests from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest by default, so I only had to follow the instructions on the readme from here https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance.

```
class PostsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "user visits index page while logged in"
    user = User.create!(email: "example@example.com", password: "letmein")
    get links_url(as: user)
    # and
    post links_url(as: user), params: { post: { title: "hi" } }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Rails 5? Rails 5 unified integration and controller tests behind `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. When you require `clearance/test_unit`, Clearance is only adding it's helpers to `ActionController::TestCase`.

I think you could do:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Clearance::Testing::ControllerHelpers
end
```

in your `test_helper.rb` file in order to get access to the helpers in those tests. However, I'm not certain the helpers themselves will work in that context.

If you could give that a try, it'd be helpful. This should be fixed in Clearance as well. Since I don't use TestUnit/MiniTest myself I sometimes miss things like this.

Comment: user = User.new(fname: "Test", lname: "User", email: "testuser@test.com", password: "password")
sign_in_as(user)
<br/>
error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
    test/controllers/goals_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:GoalsControllerTest>'

I'm new to Rails. If there is any working examples on unit testing clearance be helpful.